# Showing a Form based on Timer

Tags: c#

I am running a timer in order to communicate with hardware(serial port communication).

when a data received event is fired I need to open an another form and I should show a picture box indicating alarm.

I am facing a problem to show the child form from parent as timer is running. The child forms are getting invoked continuously as one should be invoked.

Someone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide some code demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your form with timer declare a variable for form like this:

```
private AlarmForm frmAlarm;
private bool formShowing;

private void YOUR_TIMER_EVENT_HANDLER(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(formShowing) return;

    frmAlarm=null;
    frmAlarm=new AlarmForm();
    formShowing=true;
    frmAlarm.Closed+=(a,b)=>{formShowing=false;}; 
    frmAlarm.Show();
}
```

We set `formShowing` variable to `true` when we show form. In next line we hookup `Closed` event to set `formShowing` to `false` when alarm form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to manage multiple events, each one of which should cause a single form to display.

If this is true, you need some sort of data structure to hold events received and a flag for each to indicate whether a child form has already been displayed for it.

```
Dictionary<string,bool> wasChildFormDisplayed = new Dictionary<string,bool>();

// event received - someString uniquely identifies the event
if (!wasChildFormDisplayed.ContainsKey[someString])
    wasChildFormDisplayed.Add(someString, false);

if (!wasChildFormDisplayed[someString]) {
    // ... code that opens child form ...
    wasChildFormDisplayed[someString] = true;
}
```

Note that if you are using threads, you need to use a lock to prevent concurrent reading and writing of `wasChildFormDisplayed`.